# How to completely remove all of turbolinks from a Rails 5 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, turbolinks

I've read through the other available questions and answers and they don't solve my issue. I recently looked to remove turbolinks from my project because I was having problems setting up event listeners. Suggestions for modifying the jquery to use the turbolinks equivalents weren't working, so I decided to remove it entirely for now to unblock myself.

I've done the following:

1. Remove the gem from Gemfile
2. Bundle (confirmed in the bundle turbolinks is no longer listed)
3. Removed turbolinks attributes from links in the head
4. Removed the require from the application JS
5. Restored my JS file to the original jQuery implementation

However, the problem persists on production (Heroku). Everything continues to work locally. I was inspecting the source assets on production and noticed I can find traces of turbolinks in the compiled js file. I don't know if this is causing the problem and I don't know where it's coming from so I haven't been able to remove it to test.

My JS file is set up like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('Listener setup working...');
....
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `rails assets:precompile` command in production?

Comment: @demir I did not. Is this something I need to do? I've been away from Rails for a bit and I remember this is something that crept up in a lot of issues in the past but I hadn't been experiencing any related issues since I've been working in this project in rails 5.

Comment: Yes you need to do it. JS and CSS files need to be compile. If you don't recompile, your old code will continue to work.

Comment: @demir The rest of my JS is correctly updated in the source on production - doesn't that mean that the resources are being properly compiled already? Also I believe Heroku now takes care of this, which is why as I mentioned I haven't seen issues with needing to do this since Rails 5. From the Heroku logs during deploy: `remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Could you post an example of the file where you are seeing traces of Turbolinks?